# Adding slider to home page with js

Tags: javascript, slider

a slider to homepage, I have used js within my html to animate. However when i move the js to an external file it stops working. please assist.

html

```
div class="home-container">

        <div class="slider-container">
                  
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
              src="Media/slider/2.jpg"
              alt="Roller Coaster">
            <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
              
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
              src="Media/slider/7.jpg"
              alt="Splash Park"
              >
              <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
        </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
              src="Media/slider/6.jpg"
              alt="Eating Area"
              >
              <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
        </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
              src="Media/slider/8.jpg"
              alt="Park Map"
              >
              <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
           <img
              src="Media/slider/10.jpg"
              alt="Park Map"
             >
            <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img
              src="Media/slider/11.jpg"
              alt="Park Map"
              >
            <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
         <img
              src="Media/slider/12.jpg"
              alt="Park Map"
              >
            <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
            </div>
           </div> 
        
       </div>
```

this is the js i have moved externally and the slider no longer works..

```
document.getElementById("smallA").onclick = function(){changeSize("small")};

document.getElementById("mediumA").onclick = function(){changeSize("medium")};

document.getElementById("largeA").onclick = function(){changeSize("large")};

function changeSize(c)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className="c"
}




      let slideIndex = 0;
      showSlides();

      function showSlides() {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }

        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
      }
```

I also want to add it into a thick box and keep it contained at a certain height width on fullwidth mode but keeping responsive for mobiles etc.

If someone could help point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `<script>` inside your HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: <script rel="text/javascript" href="JS/javascript.js"></script> i have put this inside my <head>

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your changeSize function:

```
function changeSize(c)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className="c"
}
```

You're setting the class name to the string "c" instead of the value of the parameter `c`. Change it to this:

```
function changeSize(c) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = c;
}
```

Also, add `defer` attribute to your opening script tag:

```
<script rel="text/javascript" href="JS/javascript.js" defer></script>
```

`defer` tells a browser to execute the script after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.